# Need to know the way to access to my Reply table?

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse



class Article(models.Model):
  '''Modelling the article section.'''
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   body = models.TextField()
   author  = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    '''Return string representation of the model.'''
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    '''Return the url of this model.'''
    return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Comment(models.Model):
    '''Modelling the comment section.'''
    article = models.ForeignKey(
       Article,
       on_delete = models.CASCADE,
       related_name = 'comments'
    )
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   author = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
       on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    '''String representation of the model. '''
    return self.comment


class Reply(models.Model):
    ''' Modelling the reply section. '''
    comment = models.ForeignKey(
        Comment,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'replys'
    )
    reply = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
       on_delete=models.CASCADE
     )

def __str__(self):
    ''' String representation of the model. '''
    return self.reply
```

I need to access my Reply table in the Detail View template(Using generic view class DetailView). I have tried so far the following command in the template.

```
article.comments.replys.all
```

Its not able to retrive any data from Reply table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is select_related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`article.comments` is a manager; you need to iterate over it to get `Comment` instances. Each one will have `.replys`.

```
{% for comment in article.comments.all %}
    {% for reply in comment.replys.all %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not working. But it's working when i use {% for comment.replys.all %}.

Comment: Oops. Yeah, that was a typo.